# I want to integrate the Aadhaar Card Authentication in PHP. I tried this code for API access but I can not get any response

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, curl

I want to integrate the Aadhaar Card Authentication in PHP. I can try this code but not get response.
How can get the response  using this code other wise where I was wrong? I can find more details of Aadhaar card api but not get response.

```
<?php

$URL = "http://auth.uidai.gov.in/1.6/public/9/9/MH4hSkrev2h_Feu0lBRC8NI-iqzT299_qPSSstOFbNFTwWrie29ThDo";

$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>         
    <Auth xmlns="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-auth-request/1.0" 
          ver="1.5" tid="public" ac="public" sa="public" 
          lk="MKg8njN6O+QRUmYF+TrbBUCqlrCnbN/Ns6hYbnnaOk99e5UGNhhE/xQ=" uid="999999990019" 
          txn="GEO.11051880"> 
          <Skey ci="20131003">Nc6DrZKFk1oQXxfgnFUl0mmtYYIPl0RGaFd2oINkpChU1++xdddMx6Dlbz6mEYs3 
                IyzChGjRXN5/al9r0runFX8LspTfMchwpxaaDIOyIUguBoYmPUqJDqTQcwey6Ntc 
                TJWFSgOvBg+omUkdbK/9GOQ5KWWrN+E0A9JN0IPU4IJqJZmsA6ETZlVoZteYtoMI 
                Ucv53qmxNPOEmJ3s4BC3ppHRRWRFMUp/eW7DFJ33W+uInZB6yekKE0dz8fYeo03w 
                2JUT1wlafL7aseb04nv5tNEbllHWafmbMpbv2pXKr+WPgytjrygt1LagGqF4a5Mr 
                /UTNwsy4m/YwlkWN0QcYVw== 
          </Skey> 
          <Uses otp="n" pin="n" bio="n" pa="n" pfa="n" pi="y" /> 
          <Data>YOn05vg5qMwElULpEmdiH0j6rM1XWcbQN0n+CFNQeazouCgjyPBH/a2SwbFgq/fF 
                CYUm+the8gQyYC36VO49NLcNcD7WdMhweoiDYgJoCX/t87Kbq/ABoAetfX7OLAck 
                /mHrTmw8tsfJgo4xGSzKZKr+pVn1O8dDHJjwgptySr7vp2Ntj6ogu6B905rsyTWw 
                73iMgoILDHf5soM3Pvde+/XW5rJD9AIPQGhHnKirwkiAgNIhtWU6ttYg4t6gHHbZ 
                0gVBwgjRzM3sDWKzK0EnmA== 
          </Data> 
          <Hmac>xy+JPoVN9dsWVm4YPZFwhVBKcUzzCTVvAxikT6BT5EcPgzX2JkLFDls+kLoNMpWe 
          </Hmac> 
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
                <SignedInfo> 
                      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /> 
                      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /> 
                      <Reference> 
                            <Transforms> 
                                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /> 
                            </Transforms> 
                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /> 
                            <DigestValue>Idd9hQtO+YAR4bjfQpNxXQ/EvXc=</DigestValue> 
                      </Reference> 
                </SignedInfo> 
                <SignatureValue>SyFAqzqtJ/VTWcR5cdxoIcsa7GMmgJo7X2Rtr+CVYZLaL2myg3HgaasaT7tPOa95 
                      xYJwnwA/pl+S7ki+W/4Kq1nraV/wxArgE5hFTUFG8G/MOcuMy9Ajd1VPvuqMGvHA 
                      gzGfV+qTcU+1lhQscYnwJqqFmoViZO7NRVwPcfgadXs=</SignatureValue> 
                <KeyInfo> 
                      <X509Data> 
                            <X509Certificate>MIICfzCCAeigAwIBAgIGAbAh09VkMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMHoxCzAJBgNVBAYT 
                                  AklOMQswCQYDVQQIEwJLQTESMBAGA1UEBxMJQmFuZ2Fsb3JlMQ4wDAYDVQQKEwVV 
                                  SURBSTEeMBwGA1UECxMVQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24gU2VydmVyMRowGAYDVQQDExFV 
                                  SURBSSBBdXRoIFNlcnZlcjAeFw0xMTA2MjgwNDQwNDRaFw0xMjA2MjgwNDQwNDRa 
                                  MGkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIEwJLQTESMBAGA1UEBxMJQmFuZ2Fsb3Jl 
                                  MRMwEQYDVQQKEwpQdWJsaWMgQVVBMQ8wDQYDVQQLEwZQdWJsaWMxEzARBgNVBAMT 
                                  ClB1YmxpYyBBVUEwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAJBEgKhZZNmH 
                                  ejKTFaSg0Z/KN6kP98/FKpPkGTlkovJxa7KX0x74I++JhObM8SkRgCGR3DBK/YZB 
                                  o0ZCbvs9czTEoDA8CBMDSFLEP5z+Zi65hdNT9XQiaeN0sSY7N4cafsS/KH/LESbM 
                                  6I5OLvSGj10aQB8KDgwItvp/7xK6/Vu3AgMBAAGjITAfMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSd3qZJ 
                                  j5lPp+1zkJJCqyZoTLLWAzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQBiGVbCITrygzpC+09u 
                                  R/l8w0hCInLusQMZeXgHcnxBGDSk1AQxKk5UfQmCwHNcRJMB5Zkj8+9n6T+/wx6D 
                                  tKDelktgIoo7w0EJ6MdVJ9Qzr5PJcYzX+ERgJEd/NNNVoPjFc2Al2odjToZdFN8+ 
                                  /upJnBH02TRb1Wq63OtcuyBIFA==</X509Certificate> 
                            <X509SubjectName>CN=Public AUA,OU=Public,O=Public 
                                  AUA,L=Bangalore,ST=KA,C=IN</X509SubjectName> 
                      </X509Data> 
                </KeyInfo> 
          </Signature> 
    </Auth>';

//setting the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    // moving to display page to display curl errors
    echo curl_errno($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
} else {
    //getting response from server
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);

    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why c tag and java and android tag? I don't see any C not even JAVA, maybe this is specific to android, but that don't seem to be.

Comment: Also don't post api keys in public forum, it will be security risk.

Comment: @VeeraKannadiga It is a test key.

Comment: @maulik Do I need to register for AUA at the uidai portal ? Can't I just use some test samples for testing purpose ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the above code you are sending request to version 1.6 while in XML data you have mentioned version 1.5 You are missing some parameters in xml data which is being sent   and those missing data are mandatory. There are some key missing in the request section.

I have solved this as per uidai guide. But haven't got successful response as you didn't provided the some keys and some keys you have provided are invalid.

```
<?php
/**
 * Read the documentation here
 * https://uidai.gov.in/images/FrontPageUpdates/aadhaar_authentication_api_1_6.pdf
 */
$adhar_card_no = "";

function buildUrl($adhar_card_no)
{
    $host = "http://auth.uidai.gov.in";
    $version = 1.6;
    $aua = "";
    $asalk = "";
    $uid = str_split($adhar_card_no);
    $url =  $host."/".$version."/".$aua."/".$uid[0]."/".$uid[1]."/".$asalk;
    return $url;
}

function requestDataBuilder($uid)
{
    $encrypted_encoded_session_key = "";
    $encrypted_pid_block = "";
    $sha256_pid_bloc_encrypted_encoded= "";
    $digital_aua_signatrure= "";
    /**
     * Authentication data to send request --Mandatory
     */
    $auth_data = [
        "uid" => $uid, //Adhaar Card No.
        "tid" => "", //Terminal Id for registered device else public
        "ac" => "", //10 char unique code, public for testing
        "sa" => "", //max length 10, same as ac possible
        "ver" => 1.6, //Current version
        "txn" => "", //AUA transaction  identifier. max length 50, not U*
        "lk" => "", //Valid License Key, max length 64
    ];
    /**
     * Uses data comprises of options as yes (y) or no (n) -- Mandatory
     */
    $uses_data = [
        "pi" => "n",
        "pa" => "n",
        "pfa" => "n",
        "bio" => "n",
        "bt" => "n",
        "pin" => "n",
        "otp" => "n"
    ];
    /**
     * Token data -- optional
     */
    $tkn_data = [
        "type" => "001", //only this option available for now which is mobile no.
        "value" => "" //Mobile no. 10 digit only no prefix
    ];
    /**
     * Meta Data Mandatory
     */
    $meta_data = [
        "udc" => $udc, //[vendorcode][date of deployment][serial number] max length 20
        "fdc" => "NA", //Fingerprint device code. use NA or NC or given code
        "idc" => "NA", //Iris device  code,  us na or NC
        "pip" => "NA", //Public IP address of the device, or NA
        "lot" => "P", //G -lat long format. p for pincode format
        "lov" => "110025" // value as per G and P- my pin change it
    ];
    /**
     * Skey data -- Mandatory
     */
    $skey_data = [
        "ci" => "", //Public key certificate Identifier --mandatory
        "ki" => "" //This is for advanced use only, --optional
    ];

    $format = '<Auth uid=”'.$auth_data['uid'].'” tid =”'.$auth_data['tid'].'” ac=”'.$auth_data['ac'].'” sa=”'.$auth_data['sa'].'” ver=”'.$auth_data['ver'].'” txn=”'.$auth_data['txn'].'” lk=”'.$auth_data['lk'].'”>';
    $format.= '<Uses pi=”'.$uses_data['pi'].'” pa=”'.$uses_data['pa'].'” pfa=”'.$uses_data['pfa'].'” bio=”'.$uses_data['bio'].'” bt=”'.$uses_data['bt'].'” pin=”'.$uses_data['pin'].'” otp=”'.$uses_data['otp'].'”/>';
    $format.= '<Tkn type=”'.$tkn_data['type'].'” value=”'.$tkn_data['value'].'”/>';
    $format.= '<Meta udc=”'.$meta_data['udc'].'” fdc=”'.$meta_data['fdc'].'” idc=”'.$meta_data['idc'].'” pip=”'.$meta_data['pip'].'” lot=”'.$meta_data['lot'].'” lov=”'.$meta_data['lov'].'”/>';
    $format.= '<Skey ci=”'.$skey_data['ci'].'” ki=”'.$skey_data['ci'].'”>'.$encrypted_encoded_session_key.'</Skey>';
    $format.= '<Data type=”X”>'.$encrypted_pid_block.'</Data>';
    $format.= '<Hmac>'.$sha256_pid_bloc_encrypted_encoded.'</Hmac>';
    $format.= '<Signature>'.$digital_aua_signatrure.'</Signature></Auth>';
    return $format;

}
$request_url = buildUrl($adhar_card_no);
$data_to_send = requestDataBuilder($adhar_card_no);
//setting the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $request_url,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/xnl'),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_to_send
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
// moving to display page to display curl errors
    echo curl_errno($ch) ;
    echo curl_error($ch);
} else {
    //getting response from server
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: @M A SIDDIQUI Thank you for your answer. I have some doubts which i would like to clear. What should I assign the values of $encrypted_encoded_session_key, $encrypted_pid_block, $sha256_pid_bloc_encrypted_encoded, $digital_aua_signatrure or else I will get these values from UIDAI portal after AUA registration ?

Comment: @Lokesh those are the keys provided to you You can find that in the doc link

Comment: I have gone through entire doc but didn't find anywhere

Comment: I am referring to aadhar authentication api 2.0 document

Answer (score 1):

> get this response

```
                                                                                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AuthRes code="NA" err="569" info="02{49951232b1f45f281c7d4f70f3cbbc57c2afd9c0d6bb5f44578bf1304d4868d4,0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0100000000000000,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1.6,20ef0f0c8d0eea98772412cea9b3b92612e3e53cb5e59152b5703165f56e8a53,efa1f375d76194fa51a3556a97e641e61685f914d446979da50a551a4333ffd7,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,efa1f375d76194fa51a3556a97e641e61685f914d446979da50a551a4333ffd7}" ret="n" ts="2017-01-17T16:07:07.664+05:30" txn="AuthDemoClient:public:20160615010712053">
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI="">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <DigestValue>PTE1p00N0sHAHhrcgK3CwOPA43+3LOY9VRpd6EefPNk=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>Rax6Fii6UcgdQB5HyaxhjltUHwfQERLCxdB+7+in29jVo+YKJrK3kwJ3Tk3nJ/+dSTQTitaSg/gY
    e+mn8E+Txepqy4SMhw9jU+DLCchYnjDUu+8MpUJ6DxlmciwFuWF0oX0KosgJhMwh5+LnkmD81O+G
    gnZupgwV/eh5NRIJ9+sSdJRYlgjcOs3pT+OcATO6TQR7QOEE0b4hSps6t5cGQX8aCFdBD5ZXe9r8
    ufYFqoD2o2DRBXeRzWkQGTODdD2Sa0hjWDA4jueZfci9Ybt8R84CnDYGflWO/88nKQClOAJX2f9F
    /ShVyjoRqStaFrmxsKIEOJ55mONmqn67wkuUWg==</SignatureValue>
        </Signature>
    </AuthRes>
```

Comment: This is not the desired result you should be getting. You are getting error number 569 which state that " Digital signature verification failed (Means that authentication request XML was modified after it was signed). " And also the AuthRes code is "NA"